# Reformatting string to integer list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to compare two lists using set. Problem is my lists are not in the right format. When the lists are compared using set, the result individually breaks down each number instead of each integer.

```
a = "[1554901200, 1554251400, 1554253200, 1554255000]"
b = "[1554901200, 1554251400, 1554253200]"
print(set(a)& set(b))

>>> set([' ', ',', '1', '0', '3', '2', '5', '4', '9'])
```

I would like the answer to be:

```
>>> set([1554901200, 1554251400, 1554253200])
```

or I would like to find a way to format the list so that set could analyze each  rather then

```
a = ["1554901200", "1554251400", "1554253200", "1554255000"]
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the list of characters. This is the output I get `set([1554901200, 1554251400, 1554253200])`.

Comment: The second time you write `a = ...` you have strings, but the first time you have numbers. These will give very different results. which do you have?

Comment: Sorry the list has been edited

Comment: @kjooma, After your edit the problem is obvious, see my answer. What you initially wrote is very different from this

Comment: It's still unclear what OP is asking: starting with two character strings that are the print images of lists, and wanting to finish with lists of ints.  I think that OP is still confused.

Comment: OP clarified in comments what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

Your `a` and `b` are strings, so when you make sets out of them, it will make sets out the length 1 strings in them. e.g. `set("abc")` is a set containing `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`. You want:

```
a = eval("[1554901200, 1554251400, 1554253200, 1554255000]")
b = eval("[1554901200, 1554251400, 1554253200]")

print(set(a)& set(b))
```

instead. This makes two lists of integers, and makes sets containing the ints in each list, then intersects them.

Make sure that you trust the inputs to eval though.

Comment: I am pulling from google sheets api and I can't change the list by simply taking out the "" around it.

Comment: This should do it

Answer (score 0):

You need the `eval()` function:

```
a = "[1554901200, 1554251400, 1554253200, 1554255000]"
b = "[1554901200, 1554251400, 1554253200]"
print(set(eval(a))& set(eval(b)))
```

results in

```
{1554901200, 1554251400, 1554253200}
```